# React native image resizing crops the image

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, image, react-native

I'm just getting started with react native. There's an image I want to resize but adding width and height acts like image cropping.
[image: this is how it looks]

Here's the code,

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <Text>Hello world!</Text>
        <Image
          source={require('./assets/logos/logo.png')}
          style={styles.logo}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  logo: {
    height: 50,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many image props available. Have a look at them from official documentation. Try the [resizeMode](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode) prop.